# Modify indentation between bullets and bullet text in slides using VBA PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I modify indentation or spacing between bullets and bullet text?

I would like to fix indentation between bullet and bullet text in all slides at once.

[image: Example Picture]

I am trying to fix it using the following code:

```
Sub Indentation()

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(2).TextFrame.Ruler
        .Levels(1).FirstMargin = 25
        .Levels(1).LeftMargin = 25
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give you any error ? Or what's wrong ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add screenshot with Example to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Now I attached an image. I want to alter space (red arrow in image space), when I tried above code, bullets are moving as well. I am not aware of exact functionality of left and first margin. Please help me! I found it hard to educate myself via online resources, they are very few online docs on this.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding a tab character using the [`vbTab`](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/builtin-constants.htm) character?

Comment: I didn't try it. How can I do that?

Comment: If you add the tab char before your text it will indent your text.

Comment: Try string concatenation using `.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = vbTab & "string"`

Comment: Thanks  medicine_man, is this without using ruler object? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: No, this is the `TextFrame` of the shape.

Comment: `ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = vbTab & "string"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the first margin to zero (or smaller than left margin)

Simplistically first margin is where the bullet is and left margin where the text starts.

Really you should be using the TextFrame2 object but this is harder to understand and is probably not needed in your usage